# Make web push notifications to show for longer

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

We integrated web push notifications in our React App with firebase, it is working fine both in foreground and in background. When the app is in foreground we attached a [event listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) (onMessage) that will handle the event and will create a push notification with the [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) Object. It is also working fine.

My question is, is there any way to increase the amount of time the notification (foreground notification) will be shown to the user? currently it is visible for 5 to 6 seconds (in Brave, Linux Mint).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot increase the time your notification is shown.